# Hive json serde selection

Tags: json, hive, hive-serde

I am confused on choosing between two json serde given in below link (
Openx and hcatolog).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/json.html

My json is not a nested json.Its a simple json.
A file having each record as json separated by newline.

Please let me know which would be apt in my case .